How calculate in Excel statistical functions for dependent variables where the independent variable is in a specific range?
I have an independent variable (say, time of day) in an Excel column and a dependent variable in another. I want to calculate statistical functions for those dependent data, where the independent variable is in a certain range (say, between 12:00 and 13:00). For average, count, max and min this can be achieved by corresponding IfS functions (like AverageIfS). How can I achieve this, for example, for the median or the standard deviation, where the corresponding IfS function does not exist?

If you're using Excel365, use FILTER to reduce the data to your required range and apply your stat function to that

On  older versions of Excel, use an if statement, e.g. =STDEV(IF(A2:A6<5,A2:A6))

Funny, =STDEV.S(IF(P7:P902<5; Q7:Q902)) works, but returns a numerically wrong value. =STDEV.S(IF(P7:P902>5; Q7:Q902)) returns a #DIV/ error. The values in P go from 0 to 2*pi() = 6.28.

In the first formula, I would guess that there might be some blanks in one or both columns of your data which are coming through as zeroes. If so, you might need to use additional conditions like (I'm reducing the number of rows to test it more easily) =STDEV.S(IF((P7:P20<5)(P7:P20<>"")(Q7:Q20<>""), Q7:Q20)).  Not sure about the second one, the result suggests that you have no data or all data values are the same.

=STDEV.S(IF(($P$7:$P$902>0)*($P$7:$P$902<0.261); Q$7:Q$902)) works. Thanks
